# Hide Bottom Tab Bar In Specific Screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am working on a mobile app and need your help. I want to hide bottom tab bar in "auth" route name. I have tried several methods from stackoverflow and google but it didn't work.
My Code:

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 * @flow strict-local
 */

import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import Auth from './views/Auth';
import AuthState from './context/auth/AuthState';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createMaterialBottomTabNavigator} from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import Home from './views/Home';

const Tab = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <AuthState>
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator initialRouteName="auth">
          <Tab.Screen name="auth" component={Auth} />
          <Tab.Screen name="home" component={Home} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </AuthState>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well a better solution can be to create layout components

- authorized and unauthorized layout component
- you will have wrapper ready to use for future updates on these screens

Comment: But i also want to use "navigation" prop in "Auth" so i can navigate to any other screen when someone successfully logins

Comment: well you also can create some protected routes, look at the blog post 
https://dev.to/olumidesamuel_/implementing-protected-route-and-authentication-in-react-js-3cl4

Comment: Please note it is react native mobile app and note the web app

Answer (score 0):

After reading your requirement, I suggest you to try an Authentication flow approch written by ['React-Navigator' API](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow) instead of putting 'Auth' page in the same Tab Navigator.

The main idea of that is using 2 Navigators.

1. Stack Navigator for 'Auth'
2. Tab Navigator for pages which logged in users can see

However, to make this flow available, you need to add Global State Management library like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start) / [React Context](https://zh-hant.reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to handle which navigator is showing.

```
<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
    {
        !redux.isLoggedIn ?
        <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen 
               name="auth" 
               component={Auth}
            />
        </Stack.Group>
        :
        <Stack.Group>
            <Stack.Screen
               name="home"
               component={YourHomeTabNavigator}
            />
        </Stack.Group>
    }
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved by Nesting Navigators

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).